# German Long term visa - Aufenthaltstitel oder gleichwertiges Dokument Nr

Tags: germany, long-stay-visas, german-residents

I'm filling in an application for a long-term internship in Germany. It has a field called ***Aufenthaltstitel oder gleichwertiges Dokument Nr./Residence permit number.*** I do not have any Residence Permit number and a quick wikipedia search shows that the visa is the residence permit. I'm confused: what should I enter in this field?

Comment: Are you filling in the application for the internship, or the application for the visa?

Comment: I'm filling in the application form for a long term visa

Comment: Long term visas are handled by Expatriates.SE, not Travel.SE.